# passing a select/option value from a view that contains a list model to a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list of models that I can call in the foreach to display in the select/options but when I try sending back a specific value to my controller to have it print in the terminal I get the following:

```
LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant
```

I know the value I'm passing back is valid since it is displaying in my options after the "id number:".

```
//my cshtml:
@model List<ViewModel.Participant>;
<form asp-action="PostNewBasketballPlayer2" asp-controller="Dashboard" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="ParticipantId">
    @{
            if(Model != null)
            {
                foreach(ViewModel.Participant i in Model)
                {
                    <option value="@i.ParticipantId">
                        @i.ParticipantFirstName @i.ParticipantLastName id number: @i.ParticipantId
                    </option>
                }                    
            }
    }
    </select>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-outline-info mt-5" type="submit">Sign up</button>
```

```
//my controller:
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Dashboard/postNewBasketballPlayer")]
public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer2(ViewModel.Participant newParticipant)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(newParticipant);
        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Dashboard");
    }
```

What I tried:

I changed the value to see if I could get a different result but I got the same response from my terminal

example:

```
<option value="12">
```

I also tried changing what I pass to my controller to an int and a string

```
public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer2(int newParticipant)
```

when I changed it to int I get back 0 in the terminal for any of the options I select even though none of the id's are zero.

```
public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer2(string newParticipant)
```

when I change it to a string i get nothing back.

I also tried making a whole separate  Participant model since ViewModel.Participant is a wrapper model that contains Participant.

```
public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer2(Participant newParticipant)
```

what the terminal printed:

```
LeagueProject.Models.Participant
```

I would however like to continue using the wrapper model for consistency in my code. It was just a test I ran to see if I could get any different results.

Comment: Can you post  the Participant class, pls?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the provided information, I have create a repository on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ChrisWong2021/leagueproject/src/master/).
The ParticipantId could be passed correctly:
[image]

Comment: the way you're passing the ParticipantId back to the controller is the same as I am. Are you getting the Id Written in the terminal? the value that is being passed back from the view is a specific part of the model (ParticipantId);  whilest the the model assigned to newParticipant in the controller is a whole model. I tried passing back the entire model by setting the value to @i in the view. while in the controller doing a writeLine on newParticipant.ParticipantId. but that gave me an error. assuming I can't pass back an entire model in select/options.

Comment: i figured out. I just had to rename the select name to the name of what I was passing in to my controller as string.